# IIS 10 Subdomain to folder

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config

help me please.

I do not speak English, so I apologize if I make mistakes
 in my writing (I use google translate) :(

Create my site with these features:

```
Bindings > *.holos.mx, holos.mx 
Path > D:\Hosteos
```

In this directory `D:\Hosteos\web.config` 
I have the rules:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <rewrite>

            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 0" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)\.holos\.mx" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <!--<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />-->
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" /><!-- .php -->
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>

        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Create this folder: `D:\Hosteos\beta`

Inside this folder I have another web.config. (D:\Hosteos\beta\web.config)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>

                <clear />
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="^life(|/)$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="test.php" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>

        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The problem is when I enter by URL subdomains (http://beta.holos.mx/life) show error 404

When I enter URL base domain (http://holos.mx/beta/life) it shows me the content of my page test.php

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change URL in your rewrite action.

Your rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 0" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)\.domain\.com" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://holos.mx/{C:1}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" /><!-- .php -->
</rule>
```